# Best Way of implementation for data synchronization and interaction between multiple user controls?

Tags: winforms, oop, design-patterns, c#-4.0, implementation

Scenario:

I have one GUI where i have multiple user controls as:

- One UserControl on left side of form that contain data filter  and selection feature.
- Another User Control on right side display/ Report data on selection from left side user control.
- Last on is Menu band that control the view of above two control on some menu selection and the view of these controls change but data remain same with some conditional modifications.

That i have do somewhat. Used a global class that have some event which will be raised to make changes/ modification in these views.
I did somewhat accordingly, but *i want to implement it in a maintainable way so that if i need to make some modification in functionality then i need not to change whole system*.

**Is there any design pattern or Model to implement such functionality where you can maintain such type of functionality in win forms??**  if yes then please provide some information with some implementation..

I know this is little subjective question, but if reference links provided then much better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a model object shared between the different parts of your UI that implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface. Use a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) to link the controls with the model.

Comment: these controls are not added on the same form. it is treated a another entity and identified with the GUID. i cannot implement this on.. lastly i have implemented singleton data source. but i want good approach rather than this.. another implemented the approach of global events which trigger in a class. everything is global there. any pattern that avoid this approach.

Comment: I don't think having the controls on different forms should be a problem. If you use a Model-View-Presenter type pattern and try to keep your UI implementation separated from the model and business logic it shouldn't matter whether the controls are on one form or ten.

Comment: can you provide me any link or tutorial about this to check whether it suits to my functionality or not..

Comment: Try googling for "winforms mvp" - there are heaps of tutorials and blog posts out there.